# Make files uploaded via XMLHttpRequest to Amazon S3 public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to set up simple JS image uploading with Amazon S3. Following is my code.

**JS**:

```
host = "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my.bucket.url/";

uploadAttachment = function(attachment) {
  file = attachment.file;
  key = createStorageKey(file);
  form = new FormData;
  form.append("key", key);
  form.append("acl", "public-read");
  form.append("Content-Type", file.type);
  form.append("file", file);
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open("PUT", host + key, true);
  // ...
  xhr.send(form);
};

createStorageKey = function(file) {
  var date, day, time;
  date = new Date;
  day = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  time = date.getTime();
  return "s3/attachments/" + day + "/" + time + "-" + file.name;
};
```

**S3 Bucket Policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my.bucket.url/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**S3 CORS**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Everything works almost fine, but **the uploaded files are not public**. Moreover, I can't even set them public from the web interface. The only thing I can do is delete them. I really need those files to be public.

If it's possible, I would really like to accomplish this without using any access keys.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Do you realize what you have done, here?  Your bucket is wide open to anonymous uploads.  By anyone, from anywhere, with no credentials needed.  That's why you can't modify the objects -- you don't even own them...  But they are in your bucket, so you're paying for them, which is why you still are allowed to delete them.  You really need to go back and read about signing and authenticating requests. Don't try to "fix" this.  You have a much bigger issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I do realize what's happening. I just want to get it working and then limit it to a single domain. Are you saying I still **have** to sign everything?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot could you please clarify: Is it possible at all to make uploaded files publicly available without signing requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

**JS**:

- Changed `host` to `my.bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`.
- `xhr.open("POST", host, true)`.
- Probably irrelevant, but I removed `acl` parameter.

**CORS:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://my.website.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**S3 Bucket Policy**: I just removed it.

**S3 Bucket Permissions**: 
[image: Granted "Upload/Delete permissions to everyone]